# Bootstrap Nested Navbars

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

How can I construct nested navbars in Bootstrap 3?

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPY86/8/) is very close to what I want, except that I want the secondary tab to always be visible. In the fiddle everything is a toggle. 
In addition I want to use navbar-inverse, but in the fiddle if I change from navbar-default to navbar-inverse, the menu no longer works!

Below I have included some code that approximates what I want. The 2nd menu should appear when the Home is clicked, and the 3rd menu should appear when Page 1 is picked, and so on.

Can this be done?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#nav1">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#nav2">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#2">Page 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#3">Page 3</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav id="nav1" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 22</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 32</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<nav id="nav2" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 23</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Page 33</a></li> 
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. the `.navbar-inverse` class

If you have replaced the `navbar-default` class by the `navbar-inverse`, then do not forget replace the same class at your javascript. Use

```
$(".navbar-inverse .in").removeClass("in").addClass("collapse");
```

instead of

```
$(".navbar-default .in").removeClass("in").addClass("collapse");
```

---

### 2. the `.collapse('hide')` method

Bootstrap has [useful methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-methods) for collapsible items. You can use `.collapse('hide')` instead of `.removeClass("in").addClass("collapse")`.

---

### 3. always be visible

If you place a navbar into the `<div class="navbar-header">` block, the navbar will be seen on a narrow screen. In this case you have to replace `$('.collapse').click(function () {` by `$('.navbar-nav').click(function () {`.

The result can turn out like this: http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/q98mtbj5/

```js
$('.navbar-nav').click(function () {
    $('.navbar-inverse .in').collapse('hide');
});

$('.navbar-toggle').click(function () {
    $('.childMenu.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.parentMenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3.0 Skeleton</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse1">Sub Menu  1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse parentMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse2">Sub Menu  2</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse3">Sub Menu  3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse1 childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse2 childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse3 childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Post Info -->
<div style='position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0; background:lightgray;width:100%;padding:2px 20px;'>
  Fork this at the <a href='http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/'>Bootrsap 3.0 Skeleton</a>
<div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Gleb, this is almost perfect. I appreciate explaining the changes that I needed to make. There is one thing that I still need. When I select a 1st level menu, the 1st level submenu is displayed and the first tab is selected. If I then select a different tab on this sub level, that tab should be selected, and the submenu should not disappear. As it is, if selecting a different tab makes the submenu disappear. How can I fix that?

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler Test http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/q98mtbj5/13/ Is it what you want to achive?

Comment: Gleb, this works, and I have been trying to a day or 2 to get the final parts to work as I would like.    First, a user selects the first tab, and the sub tab for for first tab shows up. And if the user selects any other main tab, then sub tab1 closes and sub tab 2, for example, opens. But if the user clicks on a main tab that is already selected, I want nothing to happen. Currently it collapses that menu. The 2nd issue is that selections should "stick". If a user selects a different tab on the main tab, that tab should then be active. Same for the subTab.

Comment: Gleb, I was able to get this to work with only one additional thing that I wanted. I posted another question, just on this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886386/bootstrap-nested-navbars-control-over-active-class