# Bootstrap Nested Navbars - control over "active" class

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have almost got a nested Bootstrap menu working exactly as I want it.

[image]

The menu is on two levels. The top are major menu categories, the bottom sub-categories. Selecting a major menu will turn that menu heading active and open up the appropriate sub-category, with no subcategory selected at this time. When the user selects a sub-category [for example, they select About 2 below] then that menu element is selected.

My problem is that when a user does this the major category element is de-selected and I do not want it to be.

I have JQuery code that I think I can use to control completely adding and removing the active class, however Bootstrap seems to be doing this form me.

Please see my [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/bryanschmiedeler/x5do5geo/44/).

```js
//get parent click menu
$('.parentMenu li a').click(function() {

  //compute the tag for the elment that was selected
  sel = $(this)[0].toString();
  lgt = sel.length;
  tag = sel.substring(lgt - 3,lgt);

  tt = $(".childMenu").removeClass("show");
  $(this).addClass('active');

  var subMenu = $(tag + "S");
  subMenu.addClass("show");

})

$('.parentMenu').click(function() {
  //$(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Multi-Layer Menu</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li class="active"><a href="#T1">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse parentMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#T1">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#T2">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#T3">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#T4">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="T1S" class="collapse childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="T2S" class="collapse childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="T3S" class="collapse childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="T4S" class="collapse childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**. I completely rewrote the script and added a small CSS.

1. When the user selects a sub-category, the major category element loses the focus, but not the active class. So you can add one simple css-property to color this active element in white.
2. I noticed a bug. The element of the parent menu may to get the `.active` class, but never loses it.
3. I prefer to assign the `.active` class to the `<li>` tag instead of the `<a>`.

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/kz93pmvo/

```js
// get parent click menu
$('.parentMenu li a').click(function() {

  // compute the tag for the element that was selected
  tag = $(this).attr('href') + 'S';

  // show the child menu
  selectChildMenu = $(tag);
  if( !selectChildMenu.hasClass( 'show' ) ){
    $( '.childMenu.show' ).removeClass( 'show' );
    selectChildMenu.addClass( 'show' );
  }

  // add the `active` class to the element of the parent menu
  if ( !$(this).parent().hasClass('active') ){
    $('.parentMenu .active').removeClass('active');
    $('.navbar-header .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  }
  
})
```

```css
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.navbar-header .active, 
.parentMenu .active {
 color: white !important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Multi-Layer Menu</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li><a class="active" href="#T1">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse parentMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#T1">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#T2">Sub Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#T3">Sub Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#T4">Sub Menu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="T1S" class="collapse childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="T2S" class="collapse childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="T3S" class="collapse childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="T4S" class="collapse childMenu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gleb, this breaks several other things. I want both levels to work like this: when the user selects a tab, on that level the other tabs become inactive and the selected one becomes active. Selection on one level DOES NOT AFFECT the other levels active status.

Comment: Gleb, thanks so much. This worked great. I added one thing to your code, which was to activate the selected menu in the submenu. That was pretty easy to do given your code. Please find my code on bootly.  http://www.bootply.com/zlhsWrzoqy

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler Glad to help. Your code works good. Also you can add the 
`$('.childMenu .active').removeClass('active');` line to the first part of the code, after the `$('.navbar-header .active').removeClass('active');` line.